# Телеграм бот PHP (диалог из 2 шагов)

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Есть простой бот на PHP с использованием Telegram\Bot\Api
Бот простой - вопрос->действие.
По типу

```
elseif ($text == "/unsubscribe") {
if (!empty($chat_id)) {
    $chat = ("DELETE FROM `chat_id` WHERE `chat_id` = '{$chat_id}' ");
    $conn->query($chat);
    $telegram->sendMessage(['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => 'Вы больше не будете получать уведомлений, спасибо!']);
}
```

И вот не могу понять как сделать диалог из 2 шагов?
Мне нужно построить такой диалог:
"Ввести свой период"
"Введите начальную дату"
"Введите конечную дату".
и выдать результат только после ввода конечной даты.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

В общем реализовал через запоминание ответа на первый вопрос и чат_айди в базу